# Xcode project built - Permission denied

Tags: xcode, protocol-buffers

I built an Xcode project from CMake and when I attempt to build it I get the following error.

```
PhaseScriptExecution CMake\ Rules /Users/LaserTech/NewBuild/Myjob2/NameCreate.build/Debug/lsjob2.build/Script-E70CB352E1334BCA9B8BE7C1.sh
    cd /Users/LaserTech/NameCreate-OSG-Qt5
    /bin/sh -c /Users/LaserTech/NewBuild/Myjob2/NameCreate.build/Debug/Myjob2.build/Script-E70CB352E1334BCA9B8BE7C1.sh

make: *** No rule to make target `/Users/LaserTech/NameCreate-OSG-Qt5/Myjob2/PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND', needed by `/Users/LaserTech/NewBuild/Myjob2/common.pb.cc'.  Stop.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
```

I am not sure what this means. I would appreciate it if someone could shine some light onto what I should be looking at ?

Update:

I did have thoses packages installed. I needed to simply add the path to the binaries to the environment variable. However now xcode is giving me this

```
echo "Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on protocol/common.proto"
Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on protocol/common.proto
/Users/..../cmake/osxbuild/Release --cpp_out /Users/..../Myjob2 -I /Users/.../Myjob2/protocol /Users/../Myjob2/protocol/common.proto
make: /Users/.../protobuf/cmake/osxbuild/Release: Permission denied
make: *** [/Users/../NewBuild/Myjob2/common.pb.cc] Error 1
```

Comment: do you have the following packages installed? If not, install them: libprotobuf-dev,  protobuf-compiler

Comment: just updated the post

Comment: do: `sudo mounte -o remount,exec /tmp` and `sudo make install` and try again.